# Quotient of quasi-projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety over an algebraicaly closed field and $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$ through automorphisms. Can you tell me how to prove that the quotient $X/G$ is also a quasi-projective variety. In particular: Why is this quotient a variety? Why is this variety quasi-projective?

Comment: $X/G$ is quasi-projective: It is the Proj of $\bigoplus \Gamma(X,L^n)^G$ for some ample line bundle $L$ on $X$.

Comment: Ah, I assumed $X$ projective. Maybe a GIT approach works for quasi-projective also.

Comment: For the existence of the quotient you can see exercises 2.3.20, 2.3.21, 3.3.23 and proposition 3.3.36 of Qing Liu's book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*. For quasi-projectiveness of the quotient you must read Mumford's *Geometric Invariant Theory*, I think. But I don't know if every finite quotient of a quasi-projective variety is a quasi-projective variety.